# two data aware diagrams in one pdf in reportlab

Tags: reportlab

I am trying to make a single pdf with 2 data aware diagrams. One is a bar chart which is taking data from table 1 and other is string (text box kind of thing) which gets its data from another table. 
When I run this program in reportlab, the string part(class which has the code for connecting string to database and displaying it) which is called later overwrites the bar chart diagram.
I am not finding any way to display both of them together in one pdf. 
Please suggest.

```
from rlextra.graphics.guiedit.datacharts import DataAwareDrawing, ODBCDataSource, DataAssociation  
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart3D  
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import _DrawingEditorMixin, Line, String  
from reportlab.lib.colors import red  
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter  
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image  
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle  
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY  
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter  
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image  
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle  
from reportlab.lib.units import inch  


class avg_max_min(_DrawingEditorMixin,DataAwareDrawing):  
    def __init__(self,width=1000,height=1000,*args,**kw):  
        DataAwareDrawing.__init__(self,width,height,*args,**kw)  
         self._add(self,Line(750,900,900,900),name='horline1',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(750,930,900,930),name='horline2',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(750,960,900,960),name='horline3',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(750,900,750,960),name='verline1',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(800,900,800,960),name='verline2',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(850,900,850,960),name='verline3',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,Line(900,900,900,960),name='verline4',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,String(760,945,'Average'),name='label1',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self.label1.fontSize   = 8  
        self.label1.fillColor  = red  
        self.label1.textAnchor = 'start'  
        self._add(self,String(810,945,'Minimum'),name='label2',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self.label2.fillColor  = red  
        self.label2.fontSize   = 8  
        self.label2.textAnchor = 'start'  
        self._add(self,String(860,945,'Maximum'),name='label3',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self.label3.fillColor  = red  
        self.label3.fontSize   = 8  
        self.label2.textAnchor = 'start'  
         self._add(self,String(760,915,'text'),name='label4',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,String(810,915,'text'),name='label5',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self._add(self,String(860,915,'text'),name='label6',validate=None,desc=None)  

        self.dataSource       = ODBCDataSource()  
        self.dataSource.driver                   = 'mysql'  
        self.dataSource.name                     = 'view'  
        self.dataSource.user                     = 'root'  
        self.dataSource.password                 = 'sou'  
        self.dataSource.sql                      = 'select cast(avg(diff) as char(50)), cast(min(diff) as char(50)),cast(max(diff) as char(50)) from new_table'  
        self.dataSource.associations.size       = 3  
        self.dataSource.associations.element00  = DataAssociation(column=0, target='label4.text', assocType='scalar')  
        self.dataSource.associations.element01  = DataAssociation(column=1, target='label5.text', assocType='scalar')  
        self.dataSource.associations.element02  = DataAssociation(column=2, target='label6.text', assocType='scalar')  



class final_logon(_DrawingEditorMixin,DataAwareDrawing):  
    def __init__(self,width=1000,height=1000,*args,**kw):  
        DataAwareDrawing.__init__(self,width,height,*args,**kw)  
        self._add(self,VerticalBarChart3D(),name='vertical',validate=None,desc=None)  
        self.vertical.x              = 150  
        self.vertical.y              = 200  
        self.vertical.width          = 600  
        self.vertical.height         = 600  
        self.dataSource       = ODBCDataSource()  
        self.dataSource.driver                   = 'mysql'  
        self.dataSource.name                     = 'view'  
        self.dataSource.user                     = 'root'  
        self.dataSource.password                 = 'sou'  
        self.dataSource.sql                      = 'select id, range_value, user_number from final_logon'  
        self.dataSource.associations.size       = 3  
        self.dataSource.associations.element00  = DataAssociation(column=0, target='verticalId', assocType='scalar')  
        self.dataSource.associations.element02  = DataAssociation(column=1, target='vertical.categoryAxis.categoryNames', assocType='vector')  
        self.dataSource.associations.element01  = DataAssociation(column=2, target='vertical.data', assocType='tmatrix')  

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("merged.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)  
Story = []  

Story.append(avg_max_min().go())  
Story.append(final_logon().go())  
doc.build(Story)
```

**Error which I am getting:**

```
C:\Python26\to be merged>merged.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python26\to be merged\merged.py", line 96, in <module>  
    doc.build(Story)  
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 1  
117, in build  
    BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)  
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 8  
80, in build  
    self.handle_flowable(flowables)  
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 7  
44, in handle_flowable  
    self.handle_keepWithNext(flowables)  
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 7  
11, in handle_keepWithNext  
    while i<n and flowables[i].getKeepWithNext(): i += 1  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'
```

Comment: Probably going to need to see some code.  Sounds like it's probably an issue with how you are drawing to the canvas.

Comment: I am not using a canvas...rather 2 classes one for each diagram and calling them in main...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the `rlextra` module before, but what's happening is that, as far as I know, no part of ReportLab is really designed to append to an existing file.  Instead what you need to do is generate these two images (if you want to avoid writing them to an actual file, consider using `StringIO`) and then draw them together on a single canvas.